# PHP jSON loosing precision float

Tags: php, json

i have jSON with value like :

```
"lng": 5.450698099999999
```

But when i decode the jSON, and when i echo my value, i have :

```
5.450
```

Why ?

Comment: I had a similar problem where `echo` would replace dots for commas.... Check your PHP settings and locales.

Answer (score 1):

You have two alternate ways to do it..

#### Way : 1

Decode your `JSON` data using `JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING` flag. That would be...

```
json_decode($json, false, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);
```

**Warning** : The `JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING` is available only from PHP versions **5.4.0**

#### Way : 2

Try to set the `precision` parameter on top of your PHP script like this.. (*Suggested for versions less than 5.4*)

```
<?php
ini_set('precision',16);
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/135288)

Comment: @deveLost, Did you check the demo in the answer ?